# Does NOT EXIST (in the absense of where clause in the subquery) implicitly assume that where clause is on column selected by subquery?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

Link: https://blog.udemy.com/sql-not-exists/

```
select * from customers 
where NOT EXISTS (
select customerID from orders)
```

I had always thought that the subquery should be written such that the subquery table (orders) should have a where clause to lookup the value from the outer table (customers).

However above example seems to be without where clause in the subquery.

For example I would have written it like this:

```
select * from customers c 
where NOT EXISTS (
select 1 from orders o 
where c.customerID=o.customerID)
```

So does the subquery implicitly consider where clause to be on customerID in the 1st example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The queries do different things. The first one, returns record if specific condition is true. It's like the followings:

```
select * from customers
where 1 = 0

select * from customers
where 1 = 1
```

In such cases, the condition is not referring the data in the specified table. You can use this, for example, to return or not return rows based on specific input parameter.

In your case, I expect that the `NOT EXISTS ( select customerID from orders)` will always be false, as orders exists, so no data is returned.

The second query is doing what you actually want - return customers that do not have any orders. I prefer using LEFT JOINs for such queries. In `AdventureWorks2012` it will look like:

```
select count(*) 
from Production.Product 
where NOT EXISTS (
select ProductID from Sales.SalesOrderDetail)

select count(*)   
from Production.Product c 
where NOT EXISTS (
select 1 from Sales.SalesOrderDetail o 
where c.ProductID=o.ProductID)

SELECT count(*) 
from Production.Product c 
LEFT JOIN Sales.SalesOrderDetail o 
    ON c.ProductID=o.ProductID
WHERE o.ProductID IS NULL
```

[image]

Comment: Based on the url link in the question and the query `select * from customers 
where NOT EXISTS (
select customerID from orders)` - when exactly will I use this way?

Comment: @variable I guess the author made a typo or was in a hurry, or just poor coping/editing. You can test the query in the context of the SQL Server and check the results by yourself. Your way/technique is the correct one.

Comment: Also, if you change the `NOT EXISTS` to `EXIST` you will get all customers (even the one with no orders, as your WHERE condition will always return rows / be true).

Comment: Thanks mate. Could you help me understand a scenario when if ever I would use it like how it is shown in example 1 please?

Comment: @variable You mean how to use EXISTS / NOT EXISTS? Your second query is a good example.

Comment: No I mean when will I ever use it like this `select * from customers 
where NOT EXISTS (
select customerID from orders)`?

Comment: Well, I will not use it in real scenario but it could be something like `SELECT * FROM table WHERE NOT EXISTS ( SELECT 1 FROM @DisableVisibility)` where the table variable is populating based on the user security and dictates if one is not allowed to see the data.